# Laver forcing, trees and stems

Tags: set-theory, trees, forcing

In the following snippet about Laver forcing I do not understand several things:

what is the intuition behind that $T$ extends $S$ if $T\subseteq S$.
Second, is by a stem meant ambiguously *any* node of the linearly ordered beginning of the tree in question,
from the first to last such node, or only unique last such node ?
So, are there many stems or just one ? Or is by stem even meant all of them together ?  In the -5th
paragraph they say `the stem.`
Finally what is $\prec$ in -6th paragraph, is it *any* relation satisfying the subsequent condition ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Second, is by a stem meant ambiguously any node of the linearly ordered beginning of the tree in question, from the first to last such node, or only unique last such node ?

The stem is **the unique last node** (this is implied by the second bulletpoint, which says that every node not below the stem has infinitely many successors - including the stem itself). So every condition has a unique stem.

> what is the intuition behind that $T$ extends $S$ if $T\subseteq S$?

We usually think of conditions as **building** the generic, but we can also think of them as **constraining** the generic: stronger conditions put stricter restrictions on what the generic can possibly be, with the generic filter itself ultimately putting a complete set of constraints. This all means that **more constraining conditions should be stronger**. Since the way a Laver condition constrains the generic is by limiting its possible initial segments to those which are nodes of the tree, **smaller trees yield stricter restrictions**.

> Finally what is $\prec$ in $6$th paragraph, is it any relation satisfying the subsequent condition ?

Yes.

Comment: Dear Noah your answer is quite good but I'm worried about this issue: the stem is defined only by the very first bullet and not by the second. So you cannot now use your `including the stem itself` argument can you ?

Comment: @user122424 No, both bulletpoints apply to the stem. It might be a bit clearer to write: "there is a stem $s_T$ which $(i)$  [stuff] and $(ii)$ [other stuff]." But this is a fairly standard mathematical abuse of grammar.

Comment: Dear Noah, I was initially happy with your answer, but look at what the author of the book writes: `the stem are all the nodes on the linearly ordered set, or more formally the initial segment determined by them. `

Comment: @user122424 We can conflate a node with the *set of all* nodes $\le$ it. The author could have written more clearly "the stem *is the set of* all nodes such that [stuff]." If you really care, stop thinking of the stem as a single node and think of it as a set of nodes. Either way, though, it's unique.

Comment: @Noah: In the construction of the antichain, did the author mean to say that for any $s\ge s_{p_\alpha}$ and any $n<\omega$ we have $s\color{red}{^\frown n}\in p_\alpha$ iff $n\in A_\alpha$, or am just not awake yet?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm with you on that, but I'm not currently-cognito-optimized either.